# PHP Post | HTTP Error 411. The request must be chunked or have a content length

Tags: php, http, iis, post, header

I am posting from a **linux server to an IIS server.** 
Using the code below -

```
public function PostToPage($target, $data) {

    $opts = array('http' =>
        array(
            'method'  => 'POST',
            'header'  => ["'Authorization: Basic ' . base64_encode('MYPOOLIN:znfbPLR261E=')",
                        "Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
                        "Transfer-Encoding: chunked",
                        "Content-Encoding: chunked"
                            ],
            'content' => $data,
            'ignore_errors' => 1
        )
    );

    $context  = stream_context_create($opts);
    $response = file_get_contents($target, false, $context);


    return $response;
}
```

When I try posting the data via POSTman, it works perfectly fine. However, when using the above function, it gives an error - ***HTTP Error 411. The request must be chunked or have a content length.***

When I add 'Content-Length:1024' in the header (after checking the content length via POSTman example), the POST goes on for a long time like 2-3 minutes (and possibly **times out** giving an error of 500 response code)

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

The Content-Length header must match the length of the data being posted. You cannot simply specify an arbitrary value. Doing so will cause the timeout you describe because either the request is waiting for the remaining data or has been discarded because the header didn't match the content. It's not explicitly required by the spec, but it *should* be there.

https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7230#section-3.3.2